# How to create a queue of promises that will be sync when it's empty?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have this problem in the jQuery Terminal library. I have an echo method that prints the stuff on the terminal and you can print a string, promise, or function that returns a promise or string (to simplify let's assume string or promise).

But the issue is that if you echo a few promises and strings they are not printed in order. The code was just waiting with the next echo until the promise was resolved. The problem is that it only works for one promise.

So I was thinking that I need a kind of data structure that will keep adding promises and it will wait for all promises. But I'm not sure how to do this.

The problem I have is that I can't just chain promises because the echo method needs to be synchronous when there is nothing in a queue and you print a string. But this is not how Promise A+ behaves they are always async (even `Promise.resolve()`). I have a lot of unit tests that rely on echo being synchronous and it will be break change and I don't want that.

My idea was to just create an array of promises but I'm not sure when I should remove the promise from the array so the queue can be empty when all promises are resolved and I can do synchronous call.

Something like:

```
class PromiseQueue {
    constructor() {
        this._promises = [];
    }
    add(promise) {
        this._promises.push(promise);
    }
    empty() {
        return !this._promises.length;
    }
    then(fn) {
        if (this.empty()) {
            fn();
        } else {
            Promise.all(this._promises).then(function() {
                // what do do with this._promises?
                fn();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I guess it's not that simple as in my attempt. I have no idea how to implement this behavior.

**EDIT**:

I have this two cases that I want to handle:

```js
 function render(text, delay) {
     return new Promise(resolve => {
         setTimeout(() => resolve(text), delay);
     });
 }
 term.echo(() => render('lorem', 1000));
 term.echo('foo');
 term.echo(() => render('ipsum', 1000));
 term.echo('bar');
 term.echo(() => render('dolor', 1000));
 term.echo('baz');

 setTimeout(function() {
    // this should render immediately because all promises
    // would be already resolved after 5 seconds
    term.echo('lorem ipsum');
    // so after the call I check the DOM and see the output
    // this is important for unit tests and will be huge
    // breaking change if echo don't render string synchronously
 }, 5000);
```

NOTE: echo promise and function that return a promise in this example is the same the only difference is that function is re-invoked in each re-render (e.g. when browser or container is resized).

Another example is just:

```js
 term.echo('foo');
 term.echo('bar');
 term.echo('baz');
```

that should be also synced. I need a generic solution so you don't need to know exactly what echo is doing.

Comment: If you print the object in the following sequence, string1, promise1, string2, promise2. Then you have to wait for the promise1 and it means you still need to chain it. Also. `when all promises are resolved and I can do synchronous call.` This so-called synchronous call is not synchronous because it still waits for all the promises to be resolved and it is async then.

Comment: @ikhvjs the case is when all got printed all strings and all promises and I have an empty queue. Or when I never do the echo of promise. I've found this article [Using Promises as a queue](https://dev.to/doctolib/using-promises-as-a-queue-co5) this is not what I want I want to remove elements for the queue when they are resolved. I need to change the promises only when needed.

Comment: Maybe you provide some pseudo-code examples in your question about how you echo the data?

Comment: @ikhvjs edited the question, I've found the solution to my problem while I was writing the update, added my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not even use `Promise.all` here - wait only for the first promise in the queue.

```js
const term = {
    /** an array while a promise is currently awaited, null when `echo` can be synchronous */
    _queue: null,
    echo(value) {
        if (this._queue) {
            this._queue.push(value);
        } else {
            this._echo(value);
        }
    },
    /** returns a promise if the `value` is asynchronous, undefined otherwise */
    _echo(value) {
        try {
            if (typeof value == "function") {
                value = value();
            }
            if (typeof value.then == "function") {
                this._queue ??= [];
                return Promise.resolve(value).then(console.log, console.error).finally(() => {
                    while (this._queue.length) {
                        if (this._echo(this._queue.shift())) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    this._queue = null;
                });
            } else {
                console.log(value);
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
};

function render(text, delay) {
     return new Promise(resolve => {
         setTimeout(() => resolve(text), delay);
     });
 }
 term.echo('foo');
 term.echo(() => render('lorem', 1000));
 term.echo('bar');
 term.echo(() => render('ipsum', 1000));
 term.echo('baz');
 term.echo(() => render('dolor', 1000));
 term.echo('quam');

 setTimeout(function() {
    // this should render immediately because all promises
    // would be already resolved after 5 seconds
    term.echo('lorem ipsum');
    console.log('end');
 }, 5000);
 
 console.log('echos queued');
```

Comment: It is almost exactly as code in my answer (at least this is what I have in the library it's already on GitHub) but instead of using a boolean flag, you use `this._queue` as null to indicate that the queue is empty. That code in question is actually the code when I didn't know to implement this, and then I've realized (when adding usage examples) that I already have an implementation in the code for this (in exec method). But I will use your solution with nullable queue one less variable to care about. Thanks it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While I was editing the question I've realized that this is similar to exec behavior:

```js
term.exec('timer --time 1000 "hello"');
term.exec('echo world');
term.exec('timer --time 1000 "hello"');
term.exec('echo world');
```

and I solve this using same mechanism that was proved to work.

I've added a flag:

```js
if (is_promise(next)) {
    echo_promise = true;
}
```

similar to `paused` flag.

Then when promise next is resolved. I used the same what was done in `resume()`

```js
unpromise(next, function() {
    echo_promise = false;
    var original = echo_delay;
    echo_delay = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < original.length; ++i) {
        self.echo.apply(self, original[i]);
    }
});
```

unpromise is a function that I always use. It invokes the function as then callback or calls immediately. So it's sync by default but async when needed. You can find the code on GitHub [jquery.terminal-src.js#L1072](https://github.com/jcubic/jquery.terminal/blob/f55ee4328d5e552160cf7478d9732d0aac20c373/js/jquery.terminal-src.js#L1072).

And then last thing in echo main code:

```js
if (echo_promise) {
    echo_delay.push([arg, options]);
} else {
    echo(arg);
}
```

This is not very clean code because echo is invoked multiple times but it works.  If you know a better solution please share.

Maybe this kind of code can be abstracted into single PromiseQueue interface.